# Issue while overloading the short-circuit && operator in C#

Tags: c#

I am overloading the && and The code meets all the requirements for it.

I have two classes:

```
//the class with the Main method
Four f1 = new();
Four f2 = new();
Four hh = f1 && f2;
Console.WriteLine(hh.j + "    "+hh.i);

class Four {

    public int j, i;

    public Four() {
        Console.WriteLine("vvvvvvv");
    }

    public Four(int o, int h) {
        j = o;
        i = h;
    }

    public Four(int h) {
        i = h;
    }

    public static bool operator true(Four c) {
        return (c.j!=0||c.i!=0)?true:false;
    }

    public static bool operator false(Four c) {
        return (c.j == 0 && c.i == 0) ? true : false;
    }

    public static Four operator &(Four j, Four h) {
        return (h.j != 0 && h.i != 0) & (j.j != 0 && j.i != 0) ? new Four(1, 1) : new Four(2, 2);
    }

}
```

To my understanding this is what happens when `Four hh = f1 && f2;`   gets run.

1. the overloaded `false` method of the class `Four` is invoked which returns `True` (basically meaning false) which means that the `operator &` method does NOT get invoked and this is fine. But you can not assign a boolean to `hh` so I noticed the following.

From the output though, I can see that some object is created with default values of `j` and `i` and the variable `hh` points to that object.

I do not understand how that object got created.
Can you please tell me What I am missing?
Does this mean, that if the first operand decides the outcome of the operation (which in this case it does), a new object of the same type is created? (If yes, I do not understand how It is created since the parameterless constructor is NOT called because the statement in the constructor never gets printed.)

Comment: Side note: `? true : false` is completely redundant and should be removed. The condition itself (the part before `?`) is already the value you need to return.

Comment: Thank you, Yes I just kept It to avoid confusion while debugging

Comment: Yeah, I understand what you mean, thank you.

Comment: `Four hh = f1 && f2;` <-- What are `f1` and `f2`?  You mention "(0, 0)" in a paragraph but that's entirely uncoordinated. Please provide a [mre] that fully demonstrates the use of this class and how your expectations are not being met.

Comment: I am really sorry, Just edited It.

Comment: object is not created here. Add `Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(hh, f1));`

Comment: You can't overload &&, consider `Four hh = f1 & f2;`.  Or keep it readable with And() or AndAlso() methods.

Comment: The `&` operator and the `&&` operator are **two different operators**, with different meanings. The latter _cannot be overloaded._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no new object created here, `hh` points to the already created instance referenced by `f1`.

From [language specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#11133-user-defined-conditional-logical-operators) for user-defined conditional logical operators (`&&` and `||`):

> The operation `x && y` is evaluated as `T.false(x) ? x : T.&(x, y)`, where `T.false(x)` is an invocation of the `operator false` declared in `T`, and `T.&(x, y)` is an invocation of the selected `operator &`. In other words, `x` is first evaluated and `operator false` is invoked on the result to determine if `x` is definitely false. Then, if `x` is definitely false, the result of the operation is the value previously computed for `x`. Otherwise, `y` is evaluated, and the selected `operator &` is invoked on the value previously computed for `x` and the value computed for `y` to produce the result of the operation.

So if `f1` evaluates to `false` it will be assigned to `hh`. Add `Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(hh, f1));` after the assignment and you will see that it will print `True`:

```cs
Four f1 = new();
Four f2 = new();
Four hh = f1 && f2;
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(hh, f1)); // prints True
Console.WriteLine(hh.j + " " + hh.i); // prints 0 0 cause hh is the same instance as f1
```

> I am overloading the `&&`

Also note that this statement is not actually correct - you are not overloading `&&`, which is [non-overloadable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/operator-overloading):

> Conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded. However, if a type with the overloaded `true` and `false` operators also overloads the `&` or `|` operator in a certain way, the `&&` or `||` operator, respectively, can be evaluated for the operands of that type.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I used wrong words.
Thank you very much, this fully answers my question.

Comment: @Erik_JI was glad to help! And no need to apologize for the not fully correct wording - we are not in a court =)